# Collapsible fieldset misbehaviour

Tags: views, 6

For weeks now I have been using collapsible fieldsets to display a particular node type field without problems. Sometime during the last week it inexplicably stopped working. Collapsible fieldsets still work correctly for core stuff (e.g. module listing) and the legend element appears as it used to, only the fieldset is collapsed (as it should be) and can't be expanded (the legend isn't clickable). Inspecting the HTML I can see that the value that should be in the fieldset is indeed there. What's extra curious is that in the Views GUI the fieldsets work correctly but not on the frontend of the same view.

Edit: I have been using collapsible fieldsets successfully outside of views on manually created content. This is the first time I try to use them in a view and it was how I discovered they'd ceased to function, both on the view I'm working on and the PHP code I've written myself. As per Laxman13's post, collapse.js is not being loaded on my own pages for some reason.

Comment: Please explain how you "tried to use them in a view"

Comment: @Laxman13: The particular view I'm working on was meant to replace a component I'd pieced together manually several months ago, in a content template. Since the relevant field should only show to certain users I excluded it from view and added a Customfield: PHP type to output it instead. I saw they were not clickable, then went discovered the same is true for the existing component. I alone have permission to edit templates and I have never needed to add collapse.js manually.

Comment: so did the collapsing fieldset work in other views you have created? Also is your view using fields or nodes for the display type?

Comment: I hadn't used them in a view before; but I just now did some experimentation and haven't been able to get collapsing fieldsets on any of my views, existing or new ones (except it works in the live preview).

Comment: I would assume Views wouldn't load collapse.js for all views as it isn't always needed, but I'm not sure. If you need this functionality, try adding manually

Comment: Yeah, on reflection I'm actually more surprised that it ever worked for the old component (and that it stopped) than it not working in my view. Drupal shouldn't be adding superfluous content willy-nilly. I'll add it manually for now, maybe I'll find a better solution in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the necessary JS file is not being loaded.  Check Firebug or Developer Tools, etc to see if collapse.js is being added to the `<head>` of the page.  The file can be found at YOUR_DRUPAL_ROOT/misc/collapse.js

Comment: It isn't, but why not? I've tried disabling every module I can remember adding over the last couple of weeks to no avail. The file is where it should be and, as mentioned, for core content it works fine.

Comment: This is a great example of why [using version control](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/4518/1709) for your sites it important, would allow you to roll back to a working version and compare